# Error while trying to install zsteg

Tags: ruby, gem

While trying to install [zsteg](https://github.com/zed-0xff/zsteg) on Ubuntu Server (`Linux 4.8.0-49-generic x86_64`) I encounter the following error:

```
$ sudo gem install zsteg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing zsteg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rainbow-2.2.2/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 mkrf_conf.rb

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rainbow-2.2.2/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -rubygems /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rainbow-2.2.2 RUBYLIBDIR=/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rainbow-2.2.2
/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake (LoadError)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rainbow-2.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rainbow-2.2.2/gem_make.out
```

ruby2.3, ruby-dev and rake are installed

and also tried:

```
gem update --system
```

If I don't use `sudo`, I get:
`ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.`

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just reinstalled rake and zsteg and it worked for me.

1. make sure you have ruby-dev
2. `update --system`
3. `sudo gem install rake`
4. `sudo gem install zsteg`

Comment: Thank you so much! Although my system doesn't recognize the second command you wrote, apparently the third one was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: 3rd one saved my day too!